# Asp:Button not firing while in jquery BlockUI

Tags: jquery, asp.net, blockui

I have a button which runs the following function:

```
    function BtnAddDepartment_onclick() {
        $.blockUI({ message: $('#addDivisionModal') });
```

in the Modal there is an asp:button and it doesn't fire at all

```
<asp:Button ID="BtnAddDivision" CssClass="btn" Text="Save" runat="server"
    OnClick="BtnAddDivision_Click" />
```

Is that the default behavior or am i experiencing some bug?

Comment: Can you try setting UseSubmitBehavior=false on your asp:button? The jQuery BlockUI widget changes the button behavior and it doesn't submit

Comment: sadly nothing is happening even after adding it

Answer (score 0):

you should use from onclientclick="BtnAddDepartment_onclick()"

Answer (score 0):

Try this in action button with JQUERY:

```
$('#dAgenda').parent().appendTo($("#<%=up2.ClientID%>"));
```